# GetCellData will pick single item not list. QTP and powerbuilder using VBS

Tags: qtp

Using QTP 9.5 with Powerbuilder application(Niche - If anyone has heard of it)
List in cell is : Male;Female;Unknown
If I use :

```
strCellData=PbWindow(strPbWindow), PbWindow(strPbWinow1), PbDataWindow 
    strPbDataWindow).GetCellData("#1","cellname")
```

I can get data if it is blank or one entry. If I have multiple entries seperated by ";" then it returns a General Run Error.

I have tried making

```
strCellData - arrCellData()
```

and get the same error.

I have tried to split the data by:

```
strCellData=Split(PbWindow(strPbWindow), PbWindow(strPbWinow1),    
    PbDataWindow(strPbDataWindow).GetCellData("#1","cellname"),";")
```

Once again the same error.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is because Male;Female;Unknown is not actually a valid list item. It's a known problem in QTP 9.5 and to work around it I used PBDataWindow("some_wnd").GetVisibleText and parsed the returned text. BTW, there is no such problem in QTP 10.